# AWS root domain forwarding to www subdomain when my app forces SSL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

Going to http://example.com throws up a security warning right now, because I force all my traffic over SSL, and because Amazon Route 53 doesn't allow me to point the apex of the domain to my elastic beanstalk url. Instead I point the apex to an s3 static site, that has a redirect rule to redirect to www.example.com. The problem, I think, is that that redirect rule needs access to my SSL cert to perform the redirect, but doesn't have access. How can I fix this?

Comment: Might be 'cause I didn't list *.example.com as well as example.com on the SSL cert when I added it with AWS Certificate Manager.

Comment: What is the Redirect rule you are using ?

Comment: It's the Alias A Record. I've got it working now. I just hadn't listed the bare domain. The wildcard only covers all possible subdomains, not the root itself. If someone else has this issue, please reach out. It's just a matte of adding a name when you upload the certificate in AWS certificate manager.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem, I think, is that that redirect rule needs access to my SSL cert to perform the redirect

Close, but backwards.  The http request is sent encrypted over SSL, so your server can't see the request before SSL is negotiated, which can't happen with a mismatched cert.

As has been pointed out in comments, `*.example.com` only matches exactly-one-hostname-here.example.com -- not zero and not 2 or more.  Add the additional name to your cert, to fix that.

It sounds as if you actually had 2 issues.  You can't use a bucket to redirect and have your own SSL cert on that, with just Route 53 > S3.  One alternative is Route 53 > CloudFront > S3 if for some reason you didn't want your app to handle these redirects, but wanted to stick with S3 for that.  This works too, since CloudFront can front-end a bucket and can host a custom SSL cert.

Comment: It was the one issue with names on the cert, And I just removed the S3 bucket and did an alias record for the apex.